# How to pass array elements to ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

I am having problem passing array of element to Ajax request. How it should be done?

```
var category = $('select[name="category[]"]').serialize();
$.post(host + '/form/ajax.php', {
    category:category
},
function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

In PHP I need to know how many categories element, for example:

```
 <?php echo count($_POST['category']) ?>
  // should return 3
```

HTML

```
<select name="category[]">
   <option value="1">CPU</option>
   <option selected value="2">Hard Drive</option>
</select>

<select name="category[]">
   <option value="1">CPU</option>
   <option selected  value="2">Hard Drive</option>
</select>

<select name="category[]">
   <option selected value="1">CPU</option>
   <option value="2">Hard Drive</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead.

```
var category = $('select[name="category[]"]').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing kind of double serialization when first serialize() data and later assign serialized data to a POST parameter by doing {category: category}. Instead you should send just the "category".

```
var category = $('select[name="category[]"]').serialize();
$.post(host + '/form/ajax.php',
    category,
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: What if I want to add more POST parameters?

Comment: Try to skip the call to serialize(). Just do `{category: $('select[name="category[]"]'))}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.post(host + '/form/ajax.php', {
    'category[]':category
}
```